Python multiprocessing demon CV Model dies
I am trying to write such app. Where I am need three demon Process: VideoReader, CV Model Logic, Data REST Sender and postprocessing.The model use PyTorch, so it is necessary to run in the main process. So The model process (which in the Main Process, not in the child process) dies  or freeze unexpectedly after 2-4 video (1 minute) processed. The processes have it own Queue, to send data from current to the next process. Can somebody explain me how to solve this issue, or may be tell me the better way to organise the script architecture. All processes are infinite.
In addition, I tried to catch the exception used except and catch the process exiting by using process.join() nothing helped me. So I cannot get the exit code. And I already check the Queues fullness, no one is full here.
One more strange observation. As I understood, if my Model process dies, so all processes should die too, but in this case they are still working. But the Q1 is become full, if I will add new video to videoReader
PS  If you ask, I will add some asked info. I would like to show you code, but it is too big.

This is a scheme of my solution
